Color picker works for some values in JSON file but not others
I have a JSON settings file in VS Code. Some of the settings are for colors. Naturally, it is extremely helpful to have the color picker (color decorator) appear next to the hex value to make it easy to select a color for the setting. Strangely, one of the color values shows the color picker next to it, but the others don't.
Is there a way this can be corrected, or is it a bug?
Here is the relevant section of the JSON file:
        "[Solarized Dark]": {
            "comments": "#1d9212bb"
        }

    [some lines of code]

    "better-comments.tags": [

        {
            "tag": "#region",
            "color": "#1d9212bb",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "#endregion",
            "color": "#cfbe1fff",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },

The color picker shows next to "comments" for the [Solarized Dark] entry, but not next to "color" under the "better-comments.tags" entries.

if the author of the extension that defines that setting does not mark the property as a color in the JSON scheme definition you don't get a color decoration

Thank you @rioV8 for that information. Where would I look for the scheme definition so that I can mark the properties correctly? (I'm running VS Code on Windows 11.)

in the package.json file of the extension
